# Excel 2016 formula to calculate a score with coefficients

Tags: excel

This may seem easy, but I can't find the formula to calculate the total score of a student in the table shown below.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMuyb.png)

I tried to put something like this :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B6:T6="X");B5:T5)
```

(I first removed the word "POINTS" in cells B5 to T5 in order to keep only the numerical coefficients).

It seems like the part (B6:T6="X") doesn't return a matrix as I want it to. In Excel 2019, I heard this is called "Spilling", but my computer only has Excel 2016 and I'm looking for another solution.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, but you need to do the -- trick to convert the Trues and Falses into 1s and 0s! Try this

=SUMPRODUCT(--(B6:T6="x"),$B$5:$T$5)

Comment: -- or 1* or something like that.  sure.  nice one.